# how hard is it to implement the following operations/functions in VHDL for an FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, firmware

As a firmware engineer, how do you compare the computation cost of the following operations (maybe amount of resources needed)

- addition/subtraction
- multiplication
- division
- trigonometric functions such as cosine
- square root

For FLOATING point with 32 bits calculation.

Comment: If it is a VHDL/FPGA question, you need a hardware engineer, not a firmware engineer.

Comment: For arithmetic operations (+-*/), it would heavily depend on whether you consider fixed-point or floating-point values. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Answer from a hardware (not firmware) point of view: unfortunately there is no simple answer to your question. Each function you listed has many different hardware implementations, usually between small-slow and large-fast. Moreover it depends on your target FPGA because some of them embed these functions as hard macros, so the question is not any more *what do they cost*, but *do I have enough of them in this FPGA*?

As a partial answer you can take this: with the most straightforward, combinatorial implementation, not using any hard macro, an integer or fixed-point `N`-bits adder/subtracter costs `O(N)` while a `N x N`-bits multiplier costs `O(NxN)`. Roughly.

For the other functions, it is extremely difficult to answer, there are far too many variants to consider (fixed/floating point, latency, throughput, accuracy, range...). Assuming you make similar choices for all of them, I would say: `add < mul < div < sqrt < trig`. But honestly, do not take this for granted. If you are working with floating point numbers, for instance, the adder might be closer or even larger than the multiplier because it requires mantissas alignment, that is a barrel shifter.

Comment: Fixed-point divider would also cost `O(NxN)` for fixed-point operands.

Answer (score 1):

A firmware engineer with a little hardware design knowledge would likely use premade cores for each of those functions. Xilinx, Altera, and others provide parametrizeable cores that can perform most of the functions that you specified. The parameters for the core will likely include input size and number of cycles taken for the specified operation, among many others. The resources used by each of these cores will vary significantly based on the configuration and also what vendor and corresponding FPGA family that the core is being created for ( for instance Altera Cyclone 5 or Xilinx Artix 7). The latency that the cores will have will need to be a factor in your decision as well, higher speed families of FPGAs can operate at faster clock rates decreasing the time that operations take.
The way to get real estimates is to install the vendors tools ( for instance Xilinx's Vivado or Altera's Quartus) and use those tools to generate each of the types of cores required. You will need pick an exact FPGA part, in the family that you are evaluating. Choose one with many pins to avoid running out of I/O on the FPGA. Then synthesize and implement a design for every of the cores you are evaluating. The simplest design will have just the core that you are evaluating and map it's inputs and outputs to the FPGAs I/O pins. The implementation results will give you the number of resources that the design takes and also the maximum clock frequency that the design can run at.